# Expose Interface to Entity Framework POCO lists with out referencing Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, interface, poco

I am using the POCO Template for Entity Framework 4.

I made another file to implement the partial class for the context object.  In that file I added a reference to an interface that I made.

The interface just has this one property in it:

```
IQueryable<Client> Clients { get; set; }
```

The actual generated file has this in it:

```
public ObjectSet<Patient> Clients
{
    get { return _clients  ?? (_clients = CreateObjectSet<Client>("Clients")); }
}
private ObjectSet<Client> _clients;
```

Now, [ObjectSet implements IQueryable<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412719.aspx).  But when I do this I get the following error:

> 'ClientContracts.ArupEntities' does not implement interface member 'RepositoryInterfaces.IClientRepository.Clients'. 'ClientContracts.ArupEntities.Clients' cannot implement 'RepositoryInterfaces.IClientRepository.Clients' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Linq.IQueryable'

I thought that I could do this and have it work.  Clearly I cannot...

Is there a way I can expose the POCO entity lists as an interface that is not bound to the Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not how it works. When you implement interface you must return exactly the type defined in the interface definition. Also there is some discrepancy in generic types you are using in your example - `Patient` / `Client`.

You can redefine the interface like:

```
 IQueryable<Client> ClientsQuery();
```

And in partial context class use:

```
 public IQueryable<Client> ClientsQuery()
 {
     return Clients;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. (By the way, the discrepancy was due to my mistake in putting in the example.)